# How to protect Excel xla from editing with password

Tags: excel, security, xla

I want to give users the ability to use the xla module without specifying the password but whenever someone tries to edit or view the VB source code of the module it should ask for a password.

Is this possible to do in Excel? If so how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

1- Open VBa editor and right click on the project

2- In properties dialog, you can lock the code with a password

Take a look at below

[image]